# how to avoid the overlap of the edge of graphviz

Tags: graphviz, overlap

I have Graphviz as below:

```
digraph G { 
    node [fontname = "font-awesome"]; edge [dir=none]; 

    A [label="A"];
    B [label="B"];
    c_A_B [shape=diamond];  
    {rank=same; A -> c_A_B -> B};
 
    C [label="C"];
    L1_0 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    L1_0->C;
 
    D [label="D"];
    L1_1 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    L1_1->D;  
 
    E [label="E"];  
    L1_2 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    L1_2->E;
 
    {rank=same; L1_0->L1_1->L1_2};
    {rank=same;  C; D; E;};
    c_A_B->L1_1; 

    F [label="F"];
    c_E_F [shape=diamond]; 
 
    {rank=same; E->c_E_F->F};

    L2_0 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    c_E_F->L2_0; 
}
```

which shows the graph as below, can anyone be kind to help me how to avoid the edge overlapping?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I this case in this case a solution for you can be an invisible edge in the form of:

```
    C -> D [style=invis];
```

so your example would look like:

```
digraph G { 
    node [fontname = "font-awesome"]; edge [dir=none]; 

    A [label="A"];
    B [label="B"];
    c_A_B [shape=diamond];  
    {rank=same; A -> c_A_B -> B};
 
    C [label="C"];
    L1_0 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    L1_0->C;
 
    D [label="D"];
    L1_1 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    L1_1->D;  

    C -> D [style=invis];

 
    E [label="E"];  
    L1_2 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    L1_2->E;
 
    {rank=same; L1_0->L1_1->L1_2};
    {rank=same;  C; D; E;};
    c_A_B->L1_1; 

    F [label="F"];
    c_E_F [shape=diamond]; 
 
    {rank=same; E->c_E_F->F};

    L2_0 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    c_E_F->L2_0; 
}
```

And the resulting image is:
[image]